# No such module 'AgoraRtcEngineKit'

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I'm trying to integrate the Agora video call SDK into my iOS app (swift) but I'm getting this error at the import statement despite adding the line "pod 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS', '~> 3.0.0'" to my Podfile. pod update and pod install run successfully in the terminal. I have cleaned the build folder and restarted Xcode still with no different results. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the module changed to `AgoraRtcKit` with the release of version 3.0.0. Use `import AgoraRtcKit` instead.